# Provide warning for mailings that are being edited by another user

Tags: civimail

Is there any way we can be warned that another user is editing a draft mailing?

We have multiple users who might need to edit the same mailing. Unfortunately, this creates the possibility that someone leaves the mailing open and someone else opens it and begins editing, leading to errors and the mailing not being saved correctly.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any setting in the UI or published extensions that can lock the Mailing screen if already been edited by someone else since X time.

But this can be achieved by writing custom extensions to check if anyone is on the same screen etc

Comment: OK Thanks Pradeep.